# What is the difference between suprocess.run(['ls', '-la'], capture_output=True).stdout and suprocess.check_output(['ls', '-la'])?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, pipe, stdout, popen

I am a beginner in Python and I can not seem to find a difference between the following two,

```
import subprocess

test1 = subprocess.run(['ls', '-la'], capture_output=True)
print(test1.stdout)

test2 = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-la'])
print(test2)
```

I find both **test1** and **test2** to be giving me the same thing. What is the difference?

Also two terms that I do not understand when googled about this is **'Popen constructor'** and **'pipe'**. Would be helpful if you can elaborate on both of these too and how they relate to the subprocess module.

Comment: Python's `subprocess` module offers functions with different levels of abstraction. `check_output` is a high-level and specific way to check output than the more general `run` function. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output): _`check_output` is equivalent to: `run(..., check=True, stdout=PIPE).stdout`_ ... _The full function signature is largely the same as that of `run()` - most arguments are passed directly through to that interface_ so essentially it's a convenience wrapper to simplify a common task in a lower layer of abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the `capture_output` parameter to `subprocess.run` is new in Python 3.7.

`subprocess.check_output` is the older high-level API [(docs)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#call-function-trio):

> Prior to Python 3.5, these three functions comprised the high level API to `subprocess`. You can now use `run()` in many cases, but lots of existing code calls these functions.

Older APIs remain for backwards compatibility - there's little benefit to removing them, and a long deprecation period would be needed to avoid breaking existing code.

`Popen` ("process open") is the lower level API which will be internally used by `run`, `check_output`, etc. The "Popen constructor" is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

A subprocess [pipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE) is just the subprocess API's abstraction of inter-process communication features provided by the underlying operating system. For example, using a shell `ls -la | grep needle` would connect the stdout of `ls` to the stdin of `grep` with a pipe `|`. To do similar in subprocess API, you may pass the special value `subprocess.PIPE` as the stdout handle when spawning a subprocess. You may think of a pipe as a small FIFO buffer which channels the output of one process to the input of another.